# Forma mas rápida de realizar un bucle

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, numpy, padding

He realizado un método para "padear" con ceros una señal de entrada con el fin de poder implementar el método de *UpSampling* en 2 dimensiones mediante el producto matricial a través de la matriz de convolución. Mi duda es como optimizar al máximo el bucle for que tengo en el método, ya que este método no solo trabaja para una imagen, si no para un conjunto de imágenes dadas (batch) apiladas estas en columnas (flatten). El código del método es el siguiente:

```
# Variables de entrada
BS     = 16       # Block Size
batch  = 11       # Número de inputs
i_s    = (16, 16) # Tamaño de la imagen
f_s    = (2, 2)   # Factor de escala

def msk_sampling(batch, i_s, f=(2,2), BS=16):
    # Control para batch múltiplo de BS
    pad_dim = batch
    if batch % 16 != 0:
        pad_dim = batch + (BS - batch % BS)

    n_s = (i_s[0]*f[0], i_s[1]*f[1]) # Nuevo tamaño de la imagen

    # Se construyen los índices y matrices
    idx  = np.arange(0, np.prod(i_s)*batch, batch).reshape(i_s)
    cont = -1 * np.ones(n_s)
    mask = -1 * np.ones((np.prod(n_s), pad_dim), dtype=np.int32)

    # Se crean los índices para cada imagen del batch
    for i in range(batch):
        # Se rellena la máscara con los valores de índice
        cont[::f[0], ::f[1]] = idx + i 
        cont_aux = cont.flatten()
        mask[:, i] = cont_aux

    return mask
```

El punto crítico es sin duda el bucle (tras aplicar el profiler de Spyder, el mayor tiempo de cómputo es en este punto):

```
# Se crean los índices para cada imagen del batch
for i in range(batch):
    # Se rellena la máscara con los valores de índice
    cont[::f[0], ::f[1]] = idx + i 
    cont_aux = cont.flatten()
    mask[:, i] = cont_aux
```

Gracias!

Comment: Este código parece ser que usa [tag:numpy], algo que deberías especificar tanto en el contenido de la pregunta como añadiendo una etiqueta. Es algo que ayudaría bastante a la gente que pueda responderte.

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de ver. Lo cambio!